# Expression Tree How to Identify Anonymous Type in Where Clause

Tags: c#, tree, expression

I had a similar post earlier, but I realized I was asking the wrong question.

I have a query with a couple of joins.  I am trying to add `Where(x => x.y.Code == x.x.VariableColumn)` (see historyCode below)`

I have this code:

```
var query = db.HistoryData
   .Join(db.Calendars, x => x.EventId, x => x.EventId, (x, y) => new { x, y.CompanyId })
   .Join(db.JobData, x => x.CompanyId, x => x.CompanyId, (x, y) => new { x.x, y })
   .Where(x => x.x.CompanyId == companyId && x.y.JobLevel == levelNumber);

    var historyParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(HistoryData), "hist");
    var historyCode = Expression.Property(historyParameter, $"field{levelNumber}");
    var jobParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(JobData), "job");
    var jobCode = Expression.Property(jobParameter, "code");
    var operation = Expression.Equal(jobCode, historyCode);
    var filterCondition = Expression.Lambda<Func<string, bool>>(operation, new[] { jobParameter, historyParameter });
```

When I get to The assignment to `filterCondition` I don't know how to express the Type (I have "string" but I need an anonymous type that has the HistoryData and JobData from the join.

Comment: That's likely not going to be easy. Aren't you going to do some `Select` after that? If so, couldn't you do the `Select` and then the `Where` from the question?

Comment: I could create a Type that had HistoryData and JobData properties, so that it wouldn't be anonymous.  Would I be able to build an Expression Property that was a property of a property (like x.HistoryData.VariableColumn)?

Comment: Yes, the property expression can go as deep as you want. I even have a web api where I order by dynamically (as you are doing) using `.` as property separator

Comment: Do you mind showing me an example of a two-level property expression?  Thanks!

Comment: It's just the same as what you already do for `jobCode`. For example (right below `var jobCode =...` => `var jobCodeName = Expression.Property(jobCode, "Name");`. This will generate something like `job.code.Name`. And, of course, you could continue doing the same as long as you want